# Specifying package name in function call does not work

Tags: r

I am wondering if there is a way to specify the package, e.g. with `::` when making a call to a function. The following example shows that the `do.call()` only works when the package is loaded, and the function is named directly:

```
# doesn't work
do.call("pals::brewer.spectral", args = list(n=10))
# Error in `pals::brewer.spectral`(n = 10) : could not find function "pals::brewer.spectral"


# works when package is loaded
library(pals)
do.call("brewer.spectral", args = list(n=10))
# [1] "#9E0142" "#D53E4F" "#F46D43" "#FDAE61" "#FEE08B" "#E6F598" "#ABDDA4" "#66C2A5" "#3288BD" "#5E4FA2"
```

Comment: Removing the double quotes around the function seems to work `do.call(pals::brewer.spectral, args = list(n=10))`

Comment: Of course `"pals::brewer.spectral"` doesn't work. `::` is a function (like all operators) and `do.call` doesn't parse its first parameter. It just searches the search path for the specified function name (if a character string is passed to it).

Comment: Thanks @benson23 - any way that I can remove those quotes during the call? I am trying to input a string that I build elsewhere in the script.

Comment: `fun <- "brewer.spectral"; pack <- "pals"; do.call(getFromNamespace(fun, pack), args = list(n=10))`